# Cannot load plugin `ipynb.markup` | ImportError: No module named 'IPython' when i input"pelican content"

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, data-science, pelican

i want to use "pelican content" to create a html file with a '.ipynb' file, however,it goes wrong. `(C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3) D:\jupyter-blog>pelican content
WARNING: PLUGIN_PATH setting has been replaced by PLUGIN_PATHS, moving it to the new setting name.
WARNING: Defining PLUGIN_PATHS setting as string has been deprecated (should be a list)
ERROR: Cannot load plugin`ipynb.markup
  `| ImportError: No module named 'IPython'
WARNING: No valid files found in content.
Done: Processed 0 articles, 0 drafts, 0 pages and 0 hidden pages in 0.08 seconds.`

i have checked that there's no problem with ipython,but why it still has this error.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in your error, you should install IPython or bash could not detect IPython. You should check your python version to see if there is problem with the 2 different python version on your terminal. I would share my solving experience on meeting this problem.

```
python  --version
activate python2(3)
```

And make sure the exact version of python has been attached to the `PATH` and put in the first place compared to the other version of Python.

Then use

```
python -m pip install IPython
```